# How to deal with modules inside node_modules that depends .css files?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-starter-kit

I'm working in a project where some of dependencies are a self made UI library components.

Those components has its proper `.css` file. The source structure is something like this:

```
|- src
|-|
  |- components
  |-| 
    | Component
    |-|
      |- index.js
      |- Component.js
      |- Component.css
```

The same structure is published in a build folder, with each `.js` file transpiled for a production compatible JavaScript format.

The project I consume this module vw using [React-Starter-Kit](https://reactstarter.com) and when I try to start the service using `yarn start` or `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([... path to my component inside node_modules]:13:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
/pathtomyproject/runServer.js:67
          throw new Error(`Server terminated unexpectedly with code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);
```

I guess the problem is about babel trying to read `.css` files, but I would like to know if someone have a good approach to avoid this kind of problem, using the actual boilerplate I'm using right now (React Starter Kit).

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention this. If I import that module using relative path sintax:

```
import Component, { Styles } from '../../../node_modules/@scope/my-project/Component';
```

It works as expected, obviously is nice to have syntatic sugar import

Thanks.

Comment: How do you import .CSS file, i guess issue related with import. What do you use to bundle app?

Comment: Hi @AksanaTolstoguzova, each component, imports itself styles using import syntax like this import Styles from './Component.css'

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer, I think, that import has to be:

`import Styles from './Component.css'`,

it's necessary to add .css extension to show that it's not .js and it has to be processed by css-loaders (in case if webpack is used) or other tools.

Comment: Excuse me, actually I'm importing `css` files using the extension `.css`, I forgot to put extension in my previous comment. My bad.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear, what do you try to achieve? Do you want use external component and his css for YOUR component?

Comment: Yes. For non-universal js apps, this works fine, but using in a universal js structure, I get the errors I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure that using Style from external component is correct approach..., anyway the import of external component has to without any path, it has to smth like this: `import get from 'lodash/get';`

Comment: Exactly, but when I'm working in a project that use my UI module as dependency and I import those dependencies like `import Component from '@scope/my-ui/Component'`; , I get errors and when I do the same but using relative path `../../node_modules...` It works.